# numpy multiple boolean index arrays

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, boolean, mask

I have an array which I want to use boolean indexing on, with multiple index arrays, each producing a different array. Example:

```
w = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([[False, True, True], [True, False, False]])
```

Should return something along the lines of:

```
[[2,3], [1]]
```

I assume that since the number of cells containing `True` can vary between masks, I cannot expect the result to reside in a 2d numpy array, but I'm still hoping for something more elegant than iterating over the masks the appending the result of indexing `w` by the i-th `b` mask to it.

Am I missing a better option?

Edit: The next step I want to do afterwards is to sum each of the arrays returned by `w[b]`, returning a list of scalars. If that somehow makes the problem easier, I'd love to know as well.

Comment: Are you looking for elegance or performance? Those two aren't the same.

Comment: If you are looking to just get the summations, simply use matrix-multiplication - `b.dot(w)`.

Comment: I would use dot product (I'm imitating that), but in my real example both `b` and `w` are very large and sparse, where `b` is known to only contain `1`s. I'm going for performance here.

Comment: If those are stored in regular arrays and not sparse matrices, the dot product should still be pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a list of numpy arrays you can simply use a comprehension:

```
w = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([[False, True, True], [True, False, False]])
[w[bool] for bool in b]

# [array([2, 3]), array([1])]
```

If your goal is just a sum of the masked values you use:

```
np.sum(w*b) # 6
```

or

```
np.sum(w*b, axis=1) # array([5, 1])
# or b @ w
```

…since `False` times you number will be 0 and therefor won't effect the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[w[x] for x in b]
```

Hope this helps.